# How do I create a subimage from an image in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

Given image, i, by taking four points like this

```
x=[p1,p2,p3,p4]
y=[p5,p6,p7,p8]
```

and by joining these points into a rectangle, how do I show the subset of the image enclosed by this rectangle?

Answer (score 6):

```
im = magic(100)
subIm = im(p1:p3,p5:p6,:)

imshow(subIm)
```

This assumes that p1 == p2, p3 == p4, p5 == p7 and p6 == p8

Basically, you are taking a subset of the matrix.  Depending on how your p1..p8 are set up, you will have a variation on this theme.

Comment: If the image follows MATLAB conventions (y first), you have to use <code>subIm = im(p5:p6,p1:p3,:)</code>