# Matlab: getting a subset of an image

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I am trying to get a subset of an image from 4 points. Following the solution given in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4564530/how-do-i-create-a-subimage-from-an-image-in-matlab) I located the points and sorted them in terms of maximum and minimum x,y values. After that I did:

```
subim = image(x_min:x_max,y_min:y_max,:);
```

in order to obtain a sub-image formed by the rectangle contained in `x_min:x_max,y_min:y_max`, but this didn't work.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What/how exactly didn't it work? Post the code you used

Comment: well, this is supposed to select the portion of the original image contained inside the rectangle formed by x_min, x_max, y_min and y_max; but instead it selects another portion of the image. I have checked the coordinates and I can't understand how I am getting a different section

Comment: Interchange y and x

Comment: you are my hero @Divakar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like @Divakar answer you,

matlab [image](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/image-coordinate-systems.html) works with row and columns attribute as you can see in figure 1 on this help.

And in figure 2, they show how ( x , y ) axis are define. As you can see, `y` is the rows axis and `x` the columns.

So when you are using `imshow` or `imtool` to get coordinate on a figure, it's show in (x,y) instead of (row,col). Just by inverting your coordinate, you'll get what you need.

Be aware not all library or langague use the same order, like Numpy in python is same as Matlab but OpenCV is the inverse.

Comment: I'm marking this as the correct answer, props to @Divakar for the comment in the original question