# Matlab: apply projection correction to an image subset

Tags: matlab, image-processing, transformation

Following the question I posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24162242/matlab-getting-a-subset-of-an-image/24164304#24164304), I need to apply a projective transformation to an image given 4 points.

Say I successfully segmented the QR code from an image:

[image: segmented QR code]

and I have stored in an array of points the coordinates of the QR vertices. In this case I would only need a rotation in order oto obtain the rectified image but in here:

[image: another segmented QR code]

I need to apply a projective correction to the image.

Is there a way of making these transformations knowing the coordinates of the said vertices?

**EDIT**
I solved it using @Xiang's suggestion and using HSV components of the image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly you have the 4 corner points and you want to know to which coordinates to map them in the transformed image. Well, this is up to you. You know this is a square so just choose an arbitrary height or calculate based on some measurement from the original image and generate the coordinates:

```
(0,0)
(0, size)
(size, 0)
(size, size)
```

Now you can compute the transform and apply it to the original image using `maketform`.

From Matlab docs http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/maketform.html:

> T = maketform('projective',U,X)

To apply the transform use `imtransform` and set the fields `UData`, `VData`, `XData`, `YData` to specify your source coordinate system and the new sampling coordinates you wish to transform to.

Comment: this worked like a charm, thanks a lot! One thing, though, in the second image I posted this does not work, could it be beacuse the image does not have enough information to make a good interpolation between points?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by doesn't work. What result are you getting?

Comment: I'm not sure I can upload images in a comment, let me edit the question

Comment: If you can't solve this then I suggest that you start a new question and provide full details including data and code.